# Deserializing string of format "property=whatever&property2=whatever" to an object

Tags: c#, .net, json

I am taking an HttpRequest and reading it to a string

```
var body = request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```

This body gives me a string that looks like the following:

```
"To=Jim&From=Dan+Bailey"
```

I want to serialize body to aumatically bind to an object that looks like

```
public class Letter
{
    [JsonProperty("To")]
    public string To { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("From")]
    public string From { get; set; }
}
```

Any ideas?  I tried using JsonSerializer and Newtonsoft.Json.Convert but both require a different format

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Json deserializers would only work on Json strings

You may convert the querystring to a NameValueCollection directly using the utility [ParseQueryString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms150047(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
var body = request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
var parameters = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(body);
```

For most purposes, using a NameValueCollection should suffice, but if you still need a strongly-typed object, I would suggest using either reflection, or first serialize to a json string then use Newtonsoft deserializer

```
    var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    foreach (var key in parameters.Keys)
    {
        dict.Add(key, parameters[key]);
    }

    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dict);
    var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Letter>(json);
```

Answer (score 1):

What you have is not a JSON but most likely a simple html parameter string. Looks like the format is fixed given how your class `Letter` looks like.

I guess you can just do it with Regex :

```
var match = Regex.Match("To=Jim&From=Dan+Bailey", "To=(?<To>[^&]+)&From=(?<From>[^&]+)");
var letter = new Letter() { To = match.Groups["To"].Value, From = match.Groups["From"].Value };
```

Comment: Also, I guess I should add...  I oversimplified my Letter class for this exmaple.  It has a lot more than 2 properties

Comment: You could provide more context for me to expand the regex, or you can do it yourself. The `ParseQueryString` mentioned by @Prateek is good if you don't want to handcraft the regex.